# how to return the values based on the 2 earliest dates of each value

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I had a table:

```
id | value | time(timestamp datatype)
 0     10     12:33:09 2019-04-01
 1     10     15:33:03 2019-04-01
 2     20     11:20:33 2019-04-01
 3     30     03:32:11 2019-04-01
 4     10     01:22:32 2019-04-01
 5     20     14:34:31 2019-04-01
```

I want to be able to return the 2 values based on the 2 latest timestamp only if it has at least 2 entries.

Like this:

```
value | time
  10    12:33:09 2019-04-01
  10    15:33:03 2019-04-01
  20    11:20:33 2019-04-01
  20    14:34:31 2019-04-01
```

In our case, we returned the two 10's and 20's as those are the only values with at least 2 entries.
We also chose `id: 0` and `1` as our 10's because they were the latest values to enter.

I want to know if there was a quick query to do this because all I can think of is a nested MAX() < 1 loop which I believe to be really inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by value) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by value order by time desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where cnt >= 2 and seqnum <= 2;
```

Or, use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.time <= (select t2.time
                 from t t2
                 where t2.value = t.value
                 order by t2.time desc
                 limit 1 offset 1
                );
```

The subquery returns `NULL` if there is only one row, so this returns two rows only when there are two rows -- well, assuming that the times are unique for the each value.